# How can I get a dummy database where I can use some indexing?

Tags: sql

How can I get a dummy database where I can do some indexing on tables?

What dummy database is the best for my study?

Answer (score 1):

have u tried http://sqlfiddle.com/? It is simple to use and supports mySQL and SQL Server